# Parametric Bootstrap to determine sample size capabilities

Tags: sample, nonparametric

I'm pretty new to the world of Statistics, so perhaps my understanding is lacking, but I'm interested in testing the capabilities of a smaller sample size in resolving a population mean.

My thinking was that through performing a parametric bootstrap of a known distribution and taking samples of size N (equal to my original sample), I could investigate how often it was able to accurately resolve the mean within uncertainties. Through this, I could then make an interpretation of how likely it is my original data reflects the population.

I suppose what I'm hoping to get out of posting here is a critique of my method of evaluating the effectiveness of my sample size, given that I could well be misinterpreting how a parametric bootstrap can be used in this way. If this is a viable method, I am also interested in how I could represent such uncertainty quantatively i.e. how I go from multiple variations in the bootstrap sample means to an inference about the original sample mean.

Note: The 'known distribution' I'd look to test this on is a Von Mises Distribution, fitted to the dataset using maximum likelihood estimation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.